# telerik kendoui grid not getting assigned with the parameter from additional data(on demand load of grid)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-grid

Presently I have an issue with loading the grid depends on parameter passed to the grid.
I am developing a search page In which I have a textbox and button.
I would display the grid on the click event of button taking textbox input text as parameter.

My textbox and button:

```
 <divid="SearchSection">
    <input  type="text"id="txtSearch"class="k-textbox"/> 
    <buttonid="btnSearch"  class="k-button"style="width:150px">Search</button>
</div>
```

My grid:

```
        <divid="ADUserSection"> 
        List of users in Active directory:
               @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ADUser>()
                     .Name("kADUser")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                                  {
                                   columns.Bound(p => p.UserLoginName);
                                   columns.Bound(p => p.UserDisplayName);
                                  })
                     .AutoBind(false)
                     .DataSource(ds => {
                                         ds.Ajax()
                                         .Read(read =>
                                           {
                                            read.Action("GetADUser", "ManageUsers").Data("AdditionalData");
                                            });
                                         })

                            )
               </div>
```

My JavaScript in which I am passing the additional Data:

```
       function AdditionalData() {
         debugger;
         var text = $("#txtSearch").val().trim();

          return{ searchText: text };   
            *****The Problem happens here: The searchText never get assigned value intext ****
               }
```

My script in which I am calling the click event and capturing the textbox input:

```
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#ADUserSection").fadeIn();
       $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
              debugger;
         var text =AdditionalData().toString();
          var grid = $("#kADUser").data("kendoGrid");
       grid.dataSource.read({searchText:text});
         });
          });
        </script>
```

My controller Method:

```
   publicJsonResult GetADUser([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string searchText) {
        viewmodel.searchedADUser = model.GetUserFromAD(searchText);
          return Json(viewmodel.searchedADUser.ToList().ToDataSourceResult (request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Model:

```
         public class ADUser
          {
          public string UserLoginName { get; set; }
                public string UserDisplayName { get; set; }
            }
           public List<ADUser> GetUserFromAD(string name) //Get Network Users (AD)
                {
                  var searchUser = newList<ADUser>();
                 var domainContext = newPrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
                    var groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext,           IdentityType.SamAccountName, "Domain Users");
                  UserPrincipal user = newUserPrincipal(domainContext);
                 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                    {
                      user.Enabled = true;
                       user.Name = name + "*";
                          PrincipalSearcher pS = newPrincipalSearcher();
                           pS.QueryFilter = user;
                            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = pS.FindAll();

                            foreach (var item in results)
                             {
                                  var users = new FMSystemWeb.Models.ADUser();
                                   users.UserLoginName = item.SamAccountName;
                                   users.UserDisplayName = item.DisplayName;
                                   searchUser.Add(users);
                              }
                         }
                       return searchUser;
                       }
```

My ViewModel:

```
             public class ViewModelManageUsers
              {
                public List<UserRoleList> assignedUserRole { get; set; }
                public List<ADUser> searchedADUser { get; set; }
                public List<AvailableRoles> availableRoles { get; set; }
              }
```

Please help me in looking into the issue.
I have gone through various posts which explains such scenarios and had tried to implement that, but no luck.

The javascript function

```
 function AdditionalData() {
      never gets the data assigned to my parameter 
    searchText
```

hence my controller method always gets null in the parameter and the grid don't display any result.

Comment: why are you returning an object from AdditionalData? it looks like the calling code is expecting just the string; you should start by verifying `$("#txtSearch").val()` gives you the correct value (e.g. by logging it to console)

Comment: yes I verified by placing debugger script and also putting the alert on `$("#txtSearch").val()`. I have even tried with `$("#txtSearch").val().toString()`. I could capture the input text properly but that text is not getting assigned at return.

Comment: I didn't get any proper direction on my problem, from this site hence raised an issue to telerik. telerik said it was a known issue and it has been resolved in their service pack sp2 and i have to upgarde my project to new version and it worked. But I ahd really hard time on that. so If anybody is having the same probelm please upgarde your project to newer version.

Comment: This worked very well for me using your example for the controller method, as the default controller method would not allow me to pass in my own custom 'filter'. (Default controller was ActionResult instead of JsonResult.)

Answer (score 0):

On demand event

```
  // Bouquet combo change event
    $('#BooketID').live('change', function () {
        FillChannelGridByBouquetID();
    });
```

set parameter for grid load

```
/* Load kendo grid by bouquetID*/
    function FillChannelGridByBouquetID() {
        var a = {};
        a.BooketID = $("#BooketID option:selected").val();
        var mAGrid = $('#CustomerPackageChannelKendoGrid').data('kendoGrid');
        mAGrid.dataSource.read(a);
        }
```

Grid

```
$("#CustomerPackageChannelKendoGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource:
        {
            transport:
            {
                read: "ChannelReadByBooketID",
            },
            schema:
            {
                model:
                {
                    fields:
                    {
                        SelectColumn: {type: "boolean"},
                        ChannelID: { type: "string" },
                        BooketName: { type: "string" },
                        ChannelName: { type: "string" },
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 20,
            serverPaging: false,
            serverFiltering: false,
            serverSorting: false
        },
        height: 200,
        filterable: true,
        groupable: true,
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,                                                                
        pageable:
        {
            refresh: false,
            pageSizes: [20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
        },
        columns:
        [
            {
                field: "SelectColumn", title: " ", width: "5%",
                template: "<input type='checkbox' #= SelectColumn ? checked='checked':'' # class='chkbx' />"
            },

            { field: "ChannelID", title: "ChannelID", hidden: true, filterable: false, sortable: false },
            { field: "BooketName", title: "Bouquet Name", width: "30%" },
            { field: "ChannelName", title: "Channel Name", width: "30%" },
        ]
    });
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult ChannelReadByBooketID(CustomerPackageViewModel booketModel)
        {
            var models = GetAllChannelByBooketID(booketModel.BooketID.ToString());
            return Json(models, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }      

 private List<ChannelViewModel> GetAllChannelByBooketID(string pBooketID)
        {
            Guid gBooketID;

            if (!Guid.TryParse(pBooketID, out gBooketID))
            {
                return null;
            }

            var ViewModels = _bCService.BillingUnit.ChannelRepository.Get(t => t.BooketID == gBooketID).ToList().Select(
                 md => new ChannelViewModel
                 {
                     ChannelID = md.ChannelID,
                     ChannelName = md.ChannelName,
                     BooketID = md.BooketID,
                     BooketName = md.DJBL_tblBooket.BooketName

                 }).OrderBy(o => o.BooketName);

            return ViewModels.ToList();
        }
```